# Why is WCF per call instancing mode is considered most scalable?

Tags: wcf

I have read that per call instancing mode is the most preferred when it comes to scalability. But I did not so far understood how.

The problem is I am not able to figure out what scalability is? In terms of what?

Can someone please explain in simple terms?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scalability is the capability of a system to handle a growing amount of work, for example it means if your service is called from 1 client, 2 clients or 100 clients the service keeps working in the same way, or at least reasonably well.

If you use InstanceContextMode "**Single**" your service will be able to process one call per time because only one instance of your wcf service can exists. 
So let's say one client calls your service and took 10 seconds to complete, if in that time another call to your service is coming it has to wait until the first one finished before to start, that means it's **not scalabale** because like said before, it is not capabale of handle growing amount of work (1 client good, 2 clients bad)

If on the other hand you set your service with "**PerCall**" your service will be able to have multiple instances in the same time, this means that in the previous scenario the second call will be served as soon as it arrives because another instance of your service will be created and used to execute the second call, this means it is **scalabale** because handles well a growing amount of work (1 client good, 2 clients still good)

Hope this is easy enough

Comment: Thanks, its definitely is.